# Why the footer is not showing at the bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and I am facing a problem. My footer is not showing in bottom. I want fix the footer at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/xTpfE/

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Thanks

Comment: How about adding data-position="fixed" to your footer?

Answer (score 1):

That is because it has a relative position by default applied by jquery mobile styles. So it will just drop only below its content.

To add images and float them left on footer you can modify your markup a bit.

```
   <div class="customFooter" data-role="footer">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/32x32" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/32x32" />
        </div>
         <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
```

and add rules:

```
.customFooter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #dedede;
}
.customFooter h4 {
    float:right;
}
.customFooter .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QStag/)**

Based on the comment by @frequent, i realized that you can use data-* to get this. If you want to make it as fixed position you can use the `data-position="fixed"`(But this is different from absolute positioning) you can do.

```
 <div class="customFooter" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
```

and your css becomes

```
.customFooter {
    background: #dedede;
}
.customFooter h4 {
    float:right;
}
.customFooter .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 32px; /*height of the image*/
    margin-top: -16px; /*-ve value of half the height*/
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHmW4/)**

Comment: can we change the background colour ..instead of black ..secondly why this float left is not working..I need to shift text right side

Comment: footer text I need to shift right..And want to change default background

Comment: Last can we add images over a header ? like two small image over the footer in left side

Comment: @user2648752 2 images yeah possible.

Comment: is this possible to use images on left side of footer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39029/discussion-between-user2648752-and-psl)

Comment: @user2648752 Updated tha answer and demo.. If this answered do you mind accepting it.

Comment: No CSS is required for this. jQM has its own structure and style to position footer and header.

Comment: @omar yeah I saw that in the comment in the queston. I am not jq mobile guy. Anyways for the other things he would need css.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since your answer says it all.

Comment: @Omar Thanks for commenting, otherwise i wouldn't have checked back to this answer at all... :) But the thing is position absolute and jqm fixed position does different things, not sure what op wants though, he/she already had more and more requirements beyond what question said. :)

Comment: My pleasure :) images can be positioned using jQM grid layout with some CSS to override width of blocks to position them within footer http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/grids/

Comment: @Omar nice... :) if you can post the real answer for this.. :) i will vote you up.... and can learn as well from your answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your css for the footer to

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
```

Comment: mean can you change my fiddle..?